# writing the test case for the object which returns a jsx element using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

how can i test the below object or a function which returns a Link from react-router-dom

see the below snippet. Confused on how to achieve the coverage for the below object.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { config } from './config';
const data = {
    about: {
      link: () => <Link to={config.about.href}>{config.about.text}</Link>
    },
    products: {
      link: () => <Link to={config.products.href}>{config.products.text}</Link>
    }
};

export default data;
```

or

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { config } from './config';
const data = () => {
  return {
    about: {
      link: () => <Link to={config.about.href}>{config.about.text}</Link>
    },
    products: {
      link: () => <Link to={config.products.href}>{config.products.text}</Link>
    }
  }
};

export default data;
```

any help appreciated to write the test case for the below snippet in enzyme.

Comment: What do you need tested? There's not much to test here, if anything at all

Comment: Thanks for the response , when i run the coverage where ever the Link component is there showing as  not covered . How should i cover that one

Comment: If you're trying to get coverage for the sake of coverage I guess you could write a test that calls these functions and checks that they exist. Not very useful but you'll get those coverage percentages to go up.
```const aboutLink = data.about.link()```